# Getter method returning null

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, getter-setter

I am working with JDBC. In a previous jForm I am setting the username of the user that is currently logged in with their credentials, and passing it to the following below.

```
public void setUser(String user) {   
    this.username = user;
}

private String getUser() {
    return username;
}
```

And then I am passing it to my sql statement below

```
PreparedStatement st;
ResultSet rs;
Connection conn;
try {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENTS WHERE USERNAME = (?)";
    conn = mq.getConnection();
    st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    st.setString(1, getUser());
    rs = st.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException ex) { 
    Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I am receiving a null result when running that statement. Although I used that same getter method in a jLabel and it worked fine. I'm not sure why I am receiving null.

```
  if (rs.next()) {
            mv.setVisible(true);
            mv.setUser(jTextField1.getText());
            this.dispose();
        } else {
```

This is where I am calling the setter in the previous jForm.

Comment: You are not providing enough context. Show more code.

Comment: looks like you are calling the getter before the setter.... post more code...

Comment: Not sure at all that it solves your problem but you should replace `(?)` by `?`

Comment: where is the call to the `setUser `?

Comment: It could be that you are calling `setUser` from another thread, and the field is not `volatile`. In short, best post a [mcve], and yes, it takes some time to create one.

Comment: You realise that the code you added shows that you call `setUser` after you have already executed the query (given that you call it in a `if (rs.next())`.... And yet again you are not showing enough context to really answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the table in the database does contain records.

If its true, then try storing the String returning from the getUser() into a String variable.

```
String user = getUser();
st.setString(1, user);
```

If this doesn't workout, try attaching the name of the database first in the query, like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE_NAME.PAYMENTS WHERE USERNAME = (?)";
```

Comment: @Ryan, did you try the above solution?